# Nonmonotone functions

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

I am asking for more explaining about :
If we have a function $
F\mathrm{(}x\mathrm{)}
$
 which is not monotone in $
x
$

And then we can say that the function :

$
\overline{F}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}{F}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{+}}{Mx}
$
 For $
{M}\mathrm{{>}}{0}
$

is monotone nondecreasing .

Or the function is monotone:

$
\overline{F}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}{F}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{-}}{Mx}
$
For
$
{M}\mathrm{{>}}{0}
$

nonincreasing .

Comment: What exactly are you asking? It is not true that you can make any given nonmonotone function $f(x)$ monotone by adding $Mx$ for some $M$. The function $f(x)=x\sin x$ demonstrates this, since $x\sin x + Mx$ is not monotone for any value of $M$.

Comment: No, let $F(x)=-x^2$, if you add a linear function you will always have $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}F(x)=-\infty$ which is impossible for a monotonous function.

Comment: @MPW so which functions can I make them monotone . Are  there any conditions ?

Comment: @LorenzoQ. Thanks a lot soo it's not true every time . Or in special cases we can consider that it's true ?

Comment: As far as I know the best characterization of functions in terms of monotonous functions is the fact that every function of bounded variation on a compact interval can be expressed as the difference of two increasing functions. So that gives a positive answer to your question if we substitute $Mx$ with a certain (a priori unknown, and depending on $F$) increasing function.

Comment: @LorenzoQ. So if I deal it in a compact convex space . Is it useful ?

Comment: @LorenzoQ. And I deal with it in closed intervals .

Comment: @MPW  i am trying for it .and I found that it will be really nondecreasing or nonincreasing can you explain more